# Running an .exe file with arguments using GitHub Actions

Tags: c#, github-actions, .net-4.8

I am trying to run a .exe file that was generated by building the solution using github actions. Problem is the .exe file takes in two arguments -c and -s to run. I was looking at the code where I was getting an exception. please see `args.GetUpperBound(0)` When running, I get the error as shown in the screenshot below "System.NullReferenceException". My likely guess is, I am not passing the arguments correctly. How can I pass in the arguments for the CoreServer.exe file?

```
static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int argCount = args.GetUpperBound(0);
            bool simulationMode = false; // Properties.Settings.Default.Simulation;
            bool verbose = false;
            bool logToConsole = false;
            const string startupLogName = "/var/log/corestartup.txt";
            string commandLine = "";
            // check command line arguments
            for (int i = 0; i <= argCount; i++)
             {
            //DO Something
              }
         }
```

Here is the error I am getting.

[image: Error with arguments]

Here is my .yml file. Please see Run CoreServer.exe step. I am saying -c -s, but looks like it's not taking in those arguments.

```
name: Test unit tests CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "dev" ]

  
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-2022

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: setup Msbuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.3.1

    - name: Setup NuGet
      uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.2.0

    - name: Navigate to workspace
      run: cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE

    - name: Create Build Directory
      run: mkdir _build

      
#Restore NuGet packages for CoreServer and build the Solution.

    - name: Restore NuGet packages for CoreServer
      run: nuget restore ./Core/CoreServer/CoreServer.sln

    - name: Build the CoreServer solution
      run: msbuild ./Core/CoreServer/CoreServer.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Debug"

#Restore NuGet packages for CoreClient and build the Solution.

    - name: Restore NuGet packages for CoreClient
      run: nuget restore ./Core/CoreServer/CoreClient.sln

    - name: Build the CoreClient solution
      run: msbuild ./Core/CoreServer/CoreClient.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Debug"

#List the files after build

    - name: Files after build
      run: ls ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug

#Run the CoreServer.exe

    - name: Run CoreServer
      run: ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s
 
#Upload artifact
    - name: Upload Artifact 
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
         name: my-artifacts
         path: _build/
```

Edit: In the actions when I try something like `Run: ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe --args:-c -s, it says the following:`

[image: helptext]

Edit: When I run it from a Command Prompt using -c and -s arguments, it doesn't give me the error. It shows,

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3448]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\nandukurusai\Desktop\GITSourceCode\Echo65XPlus\Core\CoreServer\Server\CoreServer\bin\Debug>CoreServer.exe -c -s
starting...
Labcyte Core Server 0.0.5.0
2023-10-05 14:24:42.032,,,ConfigController,Trace,ConfigController,,,,,,"Created Configuration Controller. Simulation-Mode: True"
2023-10-05 14:24:42.066,,1,InstrumentController,Trace,InstrumentController,,,,,,"Instrument controller - simulation mode: True"
PIC_COMM.so version 0.0.00
ISO:      0.0.0.0
Log:      0.0.0.0
2023-10-05 14:24:42.110,,1,InstrumentController,Info,EventProcessor,,,,,,"Initialize Script Engine..."
2023-10-05 14:24:43.313,,1,InstrumentController,Info,EventProcessor,,,,,,"Script Engine initialization complete."
Execute Script ID: 12
2023-10-05 14:24:43.313,,1,InstrumentController,Info,EventProcessor,,,,,,"Initialize DAQ components..."
2023-10-05 14:24:43.352,,1,InstrumentController,Info,EventProcessor,,,,,,"DAQ components initialization complete."
2023-10-05 14:24:43.353,,1,InstrumentController,Trace,InstrumentDAQ,,,,,,"Set speed of sound through BB-TB interface 2860m/s, thickness 0.8, minThickness ns 421 maxThickness ns 843"
starting cmd server...
Starting cmd processor...

Command Processor address:      localhost:3333
loading certificate: C:\Users\nandukurusai\Desktop\GITSourceCode\Echo65XPlus\Core\CoreServer\Server\CoreServer\bin\Debug\Labcyte.pfx; Port 3338
2023-10-05 14:24:43.368 MEM Usage: Working set: 86 MB, Private memory: 75 MB, Peak private memory: 75 MB
Starting ssl cmd processor...
Waiting for SSL client to connect...

SSL Command Processor address:  localhost:3338
Press x<ENTER> to quit, c<ENTER> for command mode...
```

Edit: In the C# code I see the follwing,

```
Console.WriteLine("Press x<ENTER> to quit, c<ENTER> for command mode...");
                        string userString = Console.ReadLine();//line 202
                        if (userString.ToLower().Contains("x"))//line 203
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (userString.ToLower().Contains("c"))
                        {
                            CommandMode();
                        }
```

When looking at the (screenshot)error, that is my first screenshot. On github actions, it says error on line 203. Please see the above C# code where in the comments I specified what lines 202 and 203 are.

Edit: Upon trying `echo c | ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s`, it gives the following error,

```
Run echo c | ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s
./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe: D:\a\_temp\2ac4e9fd-3794-469b-9a7f-b1d98db933ae.ps1:2
Line |
   2 |  echo c | ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe …
     |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term './Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,
     | function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
     | that the path is correct and try again.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here is the full workflow I am trying.

```
    name: Test unit tests CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "dev" ]

  
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-2022

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: setup Msbuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.3.1

    - name: Setup NuGet
      uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.2.0

    - name: Navigate to workspace
      run: cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE

      
#Restore NuGet packages for CoreServer and build the Solution.

    - name: Restore NuGet packages for CoreServer
      run: nuget restore ./Core/CoreServer/CoreServer.sln

    - name: Build the CoreServer solution
      run: msbuild ./Core/CoreServer/CoreServer.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Debug"

#Restore NuGet packages for CoreClient and build the Solution.

    - name: Restore NuGet packages for CoreClient
      run: nuget restore ./Core/CoreServer/CoreClient.sln

    - name: Build the CoreClient solution
      run: msbuild ./Core/CoreServer/CoreClient.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Debug"

#List the files after build

    - name: Files after build
      run: ls ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug

#tree for the configuration
    - name: tree
      run: tree ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/

#Run the CoreServer.exe

    - name: Run CoreServer
      run: echo c | ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s
```

Here is what the tree displays:

```
Run tree ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/
Folder PATH listing for volume Temporary Storage
Volume serial number is 00000179 3ECC:30CD
D:\A\ECHO65XPLUS\ECHO65XPLUS\CORE\CORESERVER\SERVER\CORESERVER\BIN
+---Debug
    +---SimulationData
```

Here is what the Run CoreServer error is displaying

Run echo c | ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s

```
starting...
Labcyte Core Server 0.0.5.0
2023-10-05 10:41:21.522,,,ConfigController,Trace,ConfigController,,,,,,"Created Configuration Controller. Simulation-Mode: True"
2023-10-05 10:41:22.225,,1,InstrumentController,Trace,InstrumentController,,,,,,"Instrument controller - simulation mode: True"
PIC_COMM.so version 0.0.00
ISO:  0.0.0.0
Log:  0.0.0.0
2023-10-05 10:41:22.335,,1,InstrumentController,Info,EventProcessor,,,,,,"Initialize Script Engine..."
2023-10-05 10:41:27.185,,1,InstrumentController,Info,EventProcessor,,,,,,"Script Engine initialization complete."
Execute Script ID: 7
2023-10-05 10:41:27.185,,1,InstrumentController,Info,EventProcessor,,,,,,"Initialize DAQ components..."
2023-10-05 10:41:27.295,,1,InstrumentController,Info,EventProcessor,,,,,,"DAQ components initialization complete."
2023-10-05 10:41:27.295,,1,InstrumentController,Trace,InstrumentDAQ,,,,,,"Set speed of sound through BB-TB interface 2860m/s, thickness 0.8, minThickness ns 421 maxThickness ns 843"
starting cmd server...
Starting cmd processor...
Command Processor address:  localhost:3333
loading certificate: D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Core\CoreServer\Server\CoreServer\Bin\Debug\Labcyte.pfx; Port 3338
2023-10-05 10:41:27.310 MEM Usage: Working set: 85 MB, Private memory: 75 MB, Peak private memory: 75 MB
Starting ssl cmd processor...
SSL Command Processor address:  localhost:3338
Press x<ENTER> to quit, c<ENTER> for command mode...
Waiting for SSL client to connect...
Command mode. Press x to exit command mode
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Labcyte.Core.Server.Program.CommandMode() in D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Core\CoreServer\Server\CoreServer\Program.cs:line 253
   at Labcyte.Core.Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Core\CoreServer\Server\CoreServer\Program.cs:line 209
>
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Does it work like this on your local machine? Please include that also in your question as text.

Comment: Yes on my local it works this way. On the command prompt I say CD to this directory where the .exe is and I say CoreServer.exe -c -s and it runs fine.

Comment: Please see my edit to the post.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= argCount; i++)` looks like it's almost certainly an incorrect loop condition to start with. Fundamentally you should look at line 203 in your code though. (Also, please use text rather than images for things like logs - the screenshots are *really* hard to read.)

Comment: (I'd be very surprised if the problem were really in `args.GetUpperBound(0)`, although it's confusing why you'd use that instead of `args.Length` anyway... please provide a [mcve] if there's still an issue.)

Comment: Please see my new edit when i run using command prompt. The code was written by an other team and I certainly can't change it. I am trying to find out some mechanism using github actions when I run, I get a similar kind of output like in the command prompt.

Comment: @nikhil: From your logs, it's trying to connect to server on `localhost:3338` and it's prompting for the user to proceed. Do you press `c` here to proceed on your local machine? Also, are you running this server separately on some other terminal or as a service?

Comment: Yes I am running the server separately on an other terminal as a service. At this point I don't press anything.  Very first time, I start the .exe with a '-c' and '-s' and when it runs, I just leave it as it is. Locally I start an other winforms app which connects to this server.

Comment: @Azeem can you see my edit. You are right. On the command prompt when I run, I don't press anything. But when running from GitHub actions, it wants me to press c again after it runs. So I am assuming -c and -s are just about right. But how can I specify c. Can I try ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s c

Comment: @nikhil: Try `echo c | ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s`

Comment: @Azeem tried it but doesn't work like in the edit. Also tried without echo. It says  The term 'c' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet. Any suggestions..

Comment: @nikhil: That's not about `c` but your executable. Please add its workflow step in your question.

Comment: @nikhil: Is it `Debug` or `Release` directory? What is the output of the previous step `Files after build`?

Comment: I am trying both Debug and Release of that makes any difference. i am trying Debug now.

Comment: @nikhil: But, that doesn't exist as your configuration for build is for Release and not Debug. Run `tree ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/` instead of `ls`.

Comment: @Azeem please see my edit. I also edited the yml I was trying, Running with echo c | ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s gives a slightly different error. I will update it,

Comment: I guess the problem is the github actions is not waiting after Press x<ENTER> to quit, c<ENTER> for command mode...  In case of command prompt its somehow waiting, I guess github actions is not respecting Console.Readline()

Comment: @nikhil: Your latest edit does have Debug config so that's fine now. The logs show `Command mode. Press x to exit command mode` so it worked. But, you need to show the trace to the developers on your side. Also, to run both the server and client, you need to work server in the background before running the client. You can easily find SO threads on that.

Comment: @Azeem can you help me with this. If I want to enter an other character after it goes into command mode. Lets say I want to enter h then, can I say, echo h | c | ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s ?

Comment: @nikhil: For that you need multiple inputs separated by newlines. You're using `windows-latest` runner so the default shell is PowerShell. See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72311119/passing-multiple-stdin-inputs-from-powershell-script-into-perl-script.

Comment: @Azeem Ahh I see thank you. So it will be something like  echo c, h | ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s

Comment: @nikhil: No. `echo` only adds one newline. You need multiple. Something like `"c", "h" | <your-command-here>` should work as mentioned in above thread.

Comment: @Azeem Ahh I see thank you so much

Comment: @nikhil, some feedback. Your questions seem to be posed in a needy fashion, as if you have persuaded yourself that you cannot cope, and that you want someone to rescue you. The needy material has been removed from some 30+ of your questions (by several editors) and yet it still keeps being added to new ones. I would suggest that your questions would benefit from a change of mindset - you want to know how **you** can fix an issue, rather than how someone can do it for you.

Comment: To that end [you might find this article of interest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) - it is about how the question phrasing can be read by readers as pleading (even if a question author did not intend it). In any case, there is some community consensus for technical writing, so even if this material is intended as a "politeness", it is still best omitted.

Comment: Thus, to be clear, please refrain from adding "please help" to your questions (especially where it is added more than once in the same question). Readers know you need assistance.